# Babel 7 and babel-polyfill

Tags: babeljs, babel-polyfill

After updating to babel 7 beta, looks like babel polyfill does not transpile before bundle. I updated all scoped packages like this one "@babel/polyfill": "7.0.0-beta.36". And changed imports for two files from import 'babel-polyfill' to import '@babel/polyfill'. How to use babel/pollyfill with babel env and babel 7. Should I use babel/polyfill when use useBuiltIns: 'usage', with targets?

*.babelrc.js*

```
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
let presetEnvConfig, plugins

if (nodeEnv === 'test'){
    presetEnvConfig = {targets: {node: 'current'}}
    plugins = ['istanbul']
} else {
    presetEnvConfig = {
        targets: {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 11']
        },
        modules: false
    }
    plugins = ['react-hot-loader/babel']
}

const config = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', presetEnvConfig],
        '@babel/react',
        '@babel/stage-2'
    ],
    plugins,
}
```

*types.js*

```
import keyMirror from '../../../utils/keyMirror'

export default keyMirror({
    Unassign: null,
    Reassign: null,
    QuickAssignment: null,
}, 'TagAssignmentTypes')
```

*index.js*

```
 <Assignment
     assignee={assignee}
     tagId={tagId && tagId.toString(16)}
     assignmentType={assignmentTypes.Reassign}
     onRequestClose={() => this.setState({isAssignmentInProgress: false})}
     onChange={onChange}
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

@babel/polyfill is a wrapper package which only includes imports of stable core-js features (in Babel 6 it also included proposals) and regenerator-runtime/runtime, needed by transpiled generators and async functions. This package doesn't make it possible to provide a smooth migration path from core-js@2 to core-js@3: for this reason, it was decided to deprecate @babel/polyfill in favor of separate inclusion of required parts of core-js and regenerator-runtime.

Instead of

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
```

you should use those 2 lines:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

Don't forget install those dependencies directly!

```
npm i --save core-js regenerator-runtime
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change

> @babel/stage-2 to @babel/preset-stage-2

Answer (score 0):

```
The following worked for me, add 
**.babelrc**
{
"presets": [
  ["@babel/env"]
]
}

**app.js**
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

*Install as pointed by gianmarco*
npm i --save core-js regenerator-runtime
```